# How to add to a jQuery queue dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery

---

**My problem is:**

I want to add animations to a jQuery queue dynamically. What I mean by dynamically is that the number of times, that I want this animation to be added to the queue, is some sort of user input.
(Let it be a button press, or a prompt)

**What I tried:**

I tried looking up the problem and reading the jQuery documentation on queue, but my research brought no results.

I tried adding with a keypress and with a browser prompt. I have concluded that when I try to add to the queue while an animation is running the added animations will be executed simultaneously instead after each other. I found this out by adding a console log line before each animation, and those were printed immediately after the first animation finished. (I did this by slowing down the animation to make the difference really visible)

This means that seemingly only two of animations execute regardless the number of queue additions.

I tried naming the queue, that did not help either.

**Code and JSfiddle**

This is the snippet, that causes this weird behavior:

```
  n = prompt('How many steps?');
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    box.queue(function() {
      current_left = parseInt(box.css("left"));
      box.animate({
        left: (current_left + 50).toString() + 'px'
      }).dequeue();
    })
  }
```

I created a [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/martinich/L1uktsdb/) please have a look at it!

Manual:

If you press the 'Move me' button a prompt will appear. If you enter 1 or 2 the fiddle will work as expected. If you enter a higher number, for example 5, there will only be 2 steps/movements contrary to the expected 5.

**Expectations**

What I would like to achieve is that the animation executes the number of  times that is given in the prompt to 'n'.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is probably not able to obtain the left value whilst the animation is in progress. You can use `{ left: "+=50" }` instead which increments the left position by 50px.

```js
    // find elements
    var button = $("button")
    var box = $('div')

    // handle click and add class
    button.on("click", function() {

      n = prompt('How many steps?');
      for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        box.queue(function() {
          box.animate({ left: "+=50" }).dequeue();         
        })
       }
    })
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Thank you @Koyan for you help with this post.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm grateful! This is what I was looking for!
Just for clarification: To my understanding, when I'm obtaining the left value there is no ongoing animation. It's before the new animation and after the previous one. So the animation in progress shouldn't be a problem since there isn't one. Am I wrong here?Just trying to correct my logic and learn!

Comment: @MartinTinich I am not entirely sure myself. It maybe worth setting the code up so that the left position value can be viewed at each step. I suspect something odds is happening after the first iteration. Please let me know if you find something interesting, we are all students.

Answer (score 0):

Tested the following solution and it worked fine:

```
// find elements
var button = $("button")
var box = $('div')
var current_left = parseInt(box.css("left"));

// handle click and add class
button.on("click", function() {
  n = prompt('How many steps?');
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    animate(current_left);

    current_left += 50;
  }

  function animate(leftValue) {
    box.queue(function() {      
      box.animate({
        left: leftValue.toString() + 'px'
      }).dequeue();
    });
  }
});
```

Please find it in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c2v5neoq/) what I modified.

Separated into a function the animation logic. Please check the `current_left` variable's declaration has been moved out additionally from the for loop.

Read further about function scope and hoisting [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/demystifying-javascript-variable-scope-hoisting/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It indeed works! Sorry for the scoping I should've reviewed the fiddle more times.  From previous answers it seems to me that the problem is with acquiring the left value. Your solution perfectly solves this by using an external variable for the purpose. Do you by any chance have a guess why my 'left' parameter acquire failed? Thank you in advance! Just trying to correct my logic and learn!

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the value of css left , and add to it on every step , then animate that value

```
    // handle click and add class
    button.on("click", function() {
        var n = prompt('How many steps?');
        for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) { 
            //get value of left
            current_left = parseInt(box.css("left"));
            //animate it
            box.queue(function() {    
                box.animate({
                    left: (current_left).toString() + 'px'
                }).dequeue();                    
            });   
            //add other 50
            box.css("left",current_left+50);  

        }
    })
```